# stored procedure remote call not working

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

i have stored procedure `sp_1`  in `server_A` .i am calling this SP from `Server_B`
the code is:`exec Server_A.MyDb.dbo.SP_1` in the body of sp i have complicted logic in the final step I insert result to `Table_A`.
running sp take 10 minute and return `'command complete successfully'` but tabe_A is Empty (must be filled).
i try to execute the body of script it work properly .and tble Fill as expect.
i do'nt know what is wrong...?
i try to execute `sp_1` from Another server `'server_c'` `server_d` it work fine.
 problem is with `server_B`

Comment: You can execute the procedure in the SQL Query Analyzer and check results to find possible problems, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216955%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the anwser the problem is with `Remote Query Timeout` set to `600 sec`